# What's the meaning of "git", "remote","-v" with subprocess.check_output?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I quite don't understand the meaning of this following code line.

I have found out that `subprocess.check_output` gives a byte string in `python 2.7`, but what's the meaning of `["git", "remote","-v"]` here? what's the use of having `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` ? Thanks.

```
out = subprocess.check_output(["git", "remote","-v"]), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Answer (score 2):

This command checks the output of the shell command `git remote -v`, and pipes its error to stdout. That's actually unusual, usually people use `subprocess.PIPE` so they can pipe the error wherever they want. But in this case, you would access the output of that command in out.stdout.

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.check_output` gives *the output of a shell command* as byte string. [git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) is a version control tool, to see what the command does exactly, you can read the git docs or e.g. use [explain shell](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=git+remote+-v) (`git remote` shows the list of existing remote repositories, and `-v` adds the repo urls to the output).